# OAEP Cryptanalysis with broken hash

Tags: cryptanalysis, oaep

Keeping [OAEP Cryptanalysis](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58694/oaep-cryptanalysis) in mind, about the inability to get to $M_1$ or $M_2$ given $\operatorname{OAEP}(M_1) \oplus \operatorname{OAEP}(M_2)$.

Would it be possible to get to $M_1$ or $M_2$, given $\operatorname{OAEP}(M_1) \oplus \operatorname{OAEP}(M_2)$, if the underlying hash function $\operatorname{H}$ or MGF $\operatorname{G}$ used in this instance of $\operatorname{OAEP}$ is found to be broken (invertible)?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am talking about an invertible $\operatorname{MGF}$ G and an invertible hash function H, used in $\operatorname{OAEP}$. I understand the second preimage vulnerability you mention, but I am interested in the possiblity of retrieving $M_1$ or $M_2$, given the fact that the $\operatorname{OAEP}$ instance might be broken and the fact that I only have $\operatorname{OAEP}(M_1) \oplus \operatorname{OAEP}(M_2)$.

Comment: My mention of a second preimage attack for encryption was silly! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The assumption is that an adversary somehow got around the encryption, and managed to retrieve $\operatorname{OAEP}(M_1) \oplus \operatorname{OAEP}(M_2)$, and the adversary knows that the padding scheme, $\operatorname{OAEP}$ in this case, is broken, because it was found, as an example, that SHA512 is invertible, for argument sake.

Comment: Do you know something about M1 and M2, are they both prime numbers of a specific size?

Comment: $M_1$ and $M_2$ are unknown.